# pass array hidden field in nested model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, hidden-field

I have following code in my view:

```
    <% @m1.map(&:id).each do |id|%>

    <%= b.fields_for :modul1hours do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :modul1_id, id %>
    <%= f.text_field :module_est_hours, :size => 30 %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

<%end%>
```

params passing in console

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"LJ/ZME2lHZ7VwCDgPKX6OFe326fXSXo5UB4M0cPwbCE=", "esthour"=>{"rfp_id"=>"6", "ecommerce_est_hours"=>"", "modul1hours"=>{"module_est_hours"=>"3"}, "designpages_est_hours"=>"", "cms_est_hours"=>""}, "modul1_ids"=>["12", "13", "14"], "utf8"=>"✓", "project_id"=>"second", "commit"=>"Add Todo"}
```

> Current user: admin (id=1)
>
> modul1_ids is the hidden array based on that three text box is created but when i submit the page gives me:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge' for 12:Fixnum):
```

in first textbox i passed 1
    second                2
    and in third          3

last value(3) isthe s passing that one can see in the console params `module_est_hours"=>"3`, but what about rest two fields y not passing and whats the solution for an error. Please help me.

**Edit 1**

```
    <% @m1.map(&:id).each do |id|%>

    <%= b.fields_for :modul1hours do |f| %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "modul1_ids[]", id %>
    <%= f.text_field :module_est_hours, :size => 30 %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

<%end%>
```

this code does not give the error, but also value is not stored in `modul1hours` table

The field of the `modul1hours` table are:

```
integer :modul1_id
decimal :module_est_hours
decimal :module_act_hours
integer :esthours_id
```

]

.rb

belongs_to :esthour

attr_accessible :module_est_hours,:module_act_hours

and controller

**Update**

```
    def new
@esthour = Esthour.new
 @gg =  @esthour.modul1hours.build
@project = params[:project_id]
@rfp = params[:rfp_id]

@m1 = Modul1.where(:rfp_id => @rfp.id)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @esthour }
end
```

end
**over Update**
  # GET /project_todos/1/edit

```
      def edit
      @esthour = Esthour.find(params[:id])
      end


           def create

            @project = params[:project_id]


            @esthour = Esthour.new(params[:esthour])

            user_params = params.select{|k,v| k.include?('esthour')}

            respond_to do |format|

           if @esthour.save

       get_issue_attribute_param1(user_params)

             format.html { redirect_to project_rfp_url(@project,@esthour.rfp_id), :notice => 'hours was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :json => @esthour, :status => :created, :location => @esthour }
  else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.json { render :json => @esthour.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
 end
```

*is there any build needed?eg Esthour.modul1hour.build in new def of controller coz record not saved in table?*

view

```
    <%= form_for @esthour,:rfp_id => @rfp.id,:project_id => @project do |b| %>

    <%= b.hidden_field :rfp_id, :value => @rfp.id %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :project_id, @project %>
   <table>
      <tr>    <td><b>Menutype </b></td>
    <% if  @rfp.menutype.present? %>
        <td><%= @rfp.menutype %></td> 
        <td><%= b.number_field :menutype_est_hours %></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>

      <tr>           <td> <b>Number of menu</b> </td>
    <% if  @rfp.numberofmenu.present? %>
        <td><%= @rfp.numberofmenu %></td> 
        <td><%= b.number_field :numberofmenu_est_hours %></td>
    <% end %>
   </tr>

    <tr>

        <% @m1.map(&:id).each do |id|%>

         <%= b.fields_for :modul1hours do |f| %>


          <%= f.hidden_field :modul1_id, value => id  %>
          <%= f.text_field :module_est_hours, :size => 30 %>
         </tr>
      <% end %>

     <% end %>



      </table>
     <%= b.submit 'Add Todo' %>
     <% end %>


     @esthour = Esthour.new

         @gg =  @esthour.modul1hours.build
       @project = params[:project_id]
```

Comment: Does the view code on top, and view code on `edit` are the same?

Comment: no, difference is in hidden field plz note

Comment: Can you post your controller & model code please?

Comment: is there any build needed?eg  Esthour.modul1hour.build  in new def of controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden fields aren't really the issue here

Apart from @BroiStatse's answer, I can see the issue as how you handle the params on your controller

---

**Nested Models**

Sending data to a controller sends that data to the relevant models. This is normally handled with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), but can be handled manually too

From your controller code, I *can't* see how you're dealing with your extra data, but your error is caused by the incorrect `merge` of the params

Instead of saving the data manually, I would use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to save the data, like this:

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :modul1hours
end
```

This will pass the params to your modul1hours model, where you'll then have to capture them with the relevant `attr_accessible` actions

---

**f.fields_for**

In order to get `accepts_nested_attributes_for` working properly, you have to ensure you use the `f.fields_for` function correctly.

You have to first `build` the ActiveRecord objects in your `new` controller action, like this:

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.modul1hours.build
end
```

Your problem is that you're then cycling through the ID's of your modul1hours model, yielding the `f.fields_for` artificially. Rails will only output an `f.fields_for` if the ActiveRecord object has been built in the controller:

"30" %>

[This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) gives you a better idea about this

What I would do is this:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @m1.map(&:id).each do |i|
        @project.modul1hours.build
    end
end

#app/views/projects/new.html.erb
<%= b.fields_for :modul1hours do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :id, value :id %>
    <%= f.text_field :module_est_hours, :size => "30" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm still thinking about how I would assign the ID's to the hidden field

---

**Update**

Try this:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.modul1hours.build
end
```

Replace `modul1hours` with whatever your projects `has_many` of

Comment: Yep because you're doing it right. You didn't post the correct model or controller code, so I guessed it. The problem will be that your ActiveRecord objects will not be built - I'll post an update which should show the textbox

Comment: Okay, so can you explain what your project `has_many` of? Also, can you post your new `fields_for` code

Comment: class Modul1hour < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :esthour

 attr_accessible :module_est_hours,:module_act_hours

end

Comment: class Esthour < ActiveRecord::Base
   
 **belongs_to :rfp**
 has_many :modul1hours
accepts_nested_attributes_for :modul1hours end

Comment: Thanks for the updates! Okay, looking at it more, you've got a much more complicated variable setup than I presumed before. Can you post your `new` action from your controller again?

Comment: Yes I am here - I don't see where you're building your objects in the `new` action?

Comment: plz scroll down main explaination @esthour.modul1hours.build

Comment: plz see update section in my question explanation a new method

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :modul1_id, id %>
```

You are saying that you want the hidden field binded with modul1hour `modul1_id` method and options being `id`. Second parameter for FormBuilder hidden_field is expected to be a hash (which is then merged against default options). To do what you want do:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :modul1_id, value: id %>
```

Comment: you just took my answer :).

Comment: NO ERROR BUT value is nt saved in db

Comment: I've just noticed your create action - could you please paste your whole view, as it seems you didn't build your form correctly.

Comment: is there any build needed?eg  Esthour.modul1hour.build  in new def of controller coz record not saved in table

Comment: Now even textbox not appear for nested model!