# data not saved in nested table with hidden field(array)passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms

when I submit the form :

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"LJ/ZME2lHZ7VwCDgPKX6OFe326fXSXo5UB4M0cPwbCE=", "project_id"=>"second", "utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Add Todo", "esthour"=>{"rfp_id"=>"2", "cms_est_hours"=>"", "modul1hours_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"module_est_hours"=>"11", "modul1_id"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"module_est_hours"=>"111", "modul1_id"=>"4"}}, "designpages_est_hours"=>"", "ecommerce_est_hours"=>""}}
```

**models**

```
class Esthour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modul1hours
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :modul1hours
end

class Modul1hour < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :esthour
  attr_accessible :module_est_hours,:module_act_hours,:modul1_id,:esthour_id
end
```

**view**

```
<% @m1.map(&:id).each do |id|%>

  <%= b.fields_for :modul1hours, @esthour.modul1hours.build do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :modul1_id, :value => id %>

    <%= f.text_field :module_est_hours, :size => 30 %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
def new
  @esthour = Esthour.new
  @project = params[:project_id]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @esthour }
  end
end
```

You can see my earlier question regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539040/pass-array-hidden-field-in-nested-model-rails).

I'm waiting for valuable reply. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your `create` action in addition to the `new` action you've already posted.

Comment: `def create

     @project = params[:project_id]


        @esthour = Esthour.new(params[:esthour])



    respond_to do |format|

      if @esthour.save

      format.html { redirect_to project_rfp_url(@project,@esthour.rfp_id), :notice =>   'hours was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @esthour, :status => :created, :location => @esthour }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @esthour.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
     end`

Comment: are there any errors reported.  When you check your log file do you see the correct insert query?

Comment: @Anish please edit your post, and add the action code in it.

Comment: @vinodadhikary there is no error,@majioa action code is already there